# Camel-CXF doesn't add soap:Header to Request when run inside Apache Karaf

Tags: java, soap, apache-camel, cxf, apache-karaf

I'm using Camel (2.16.3) to call a Webservice (see WSDL below). If I run my Route Standalone with the *camel:run* maven command, everything works fine and the Request is like so:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Header>
        <Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://tempuri.org/OutboundItemTransferIISWebService/OutboundItemTransferIISWebService/ItemTransfer</Action>
        <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:uuid:17fba6c9-daa8-41cb-a5a5-2806165d705b</MessageID>
        <To xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://localhost:8765/wc3/entw/OutboundItemTransferIISWebService.svc</To>
        <ReplyTo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
            <Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</Address>
        </ReplyTo>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <ns2:ItemTransfer xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x60780" xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/OutboundItemTransferIISWebService/"><ns2:p_OutboundItem/>
            <ns2:p_ItemFilter></ns2:p_ItemFilter>
            <ns2:p_ItemMaxFilter>100</ns2:p_ItemMaxFilter>
        </ns2:ItemTransfer>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But if I deploy my Project to a Karaf (4.0.4) Installation and trigger the Request, the soap:Header is missing:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns2:ItemTransfer xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x60780" xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/OutboundItemTransferIISWebService/"><ns2:p_OutboundItem/>
            <ns2:p_ItemFilter></ns2:p_ItemFilter>
            <ns2:p_ItemMaxFilter>100</ns2:p_ItemMaxFilter>
        </ns2 :ItemTransfer>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Because for the Server, which is called, the Header is required I get an SOAP Fault back.

---

**Attachments**

Following the Spring configuration which defines the CXF Endpoint:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="itemTransfer"
    address="${navision.ws.base.url}/OutboundItemTransferIISWebService.svc"
    wsdlURL="wsdl/OutboundItemTransferIISWebService.wsdl"
    serviceClass="org.tempuri.outbounditemtransferiiswebservice.OutboundItemTransferIISWebService"
    endpointName="ns:WSHttpBinding_OutboundItemTransferIISWebService"
    serviceName="ns:OutboundItemTransferIISWebService"
    xmlns:ns="http://tempuri.org/OutboundItemTransferIISWebService/"
    loggingFeatureEnabled="true">
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

and the Route (in Java DSL) which trigger the request:

```
from(ACTIVEMQ_UPDATE_ITEMS).routeId("Read all Items from the Webservice into MongoDB")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, logger, "Read the next {{navision.ws.chunk.size}} Items! Filter: '${body}'")
    .setHeader(Masterdata.HEADER_CHUNK_SIZE).simple("{{navision.ws.chunk.size}}")
    .bean(InitialItemImport.class, "createItemTransferRequest")
    .to("cxf:bean:itemTransfer?dataFormat=POJO")
    .bean(InitialItemImport.class, "itemTransferResponseToList")
    .split(body()).parallelProcessing()
        .bean(InitialItemImport.class, "convertItemToUpsert")
        .to("mongodb:mongo?database={{mongo.database}}&collection=articles&operation=update")
    .end()
    .choice()
        .when(method(InitialItemImport.class, "shouldTriggerNext"))
            .bean(InitialItemImport.class, "createNextFilter")
            .to(ACTIVEMQ_UPDATE_ITEMS)
        .otherwise()
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, logger, "Finished Full-Update of Items")
    .end();
```

and the WSDL which defines the Service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="OutboundItemTransferIISWebService"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/OutboundItemTransferIISWebService/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex"
    xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/OutboundItemTransferIISWebService/"
    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy"
    xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract"
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
    xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_OutboundItemTransferIISWebService_policy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <wsaw:UsingAddressing />
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
            targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/OutboundItemTransferIISWebService/">
            <xsd:element name="ItemTransfer">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="p_OutboundItem"
                            type="q1:ItemData" xmlns:q1="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x60780" />
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="p_ItemFilter"
                            type="xsd:string" />
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="p_ItemMaxFilter"
                            type="xsd:int" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="ItemTransferResponse">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                            name="ItemTransferResult" type="q2:ItemData"
                            xmlns:q2="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x60780" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:schema>
        <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
            targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x60780">
            <xsd:complexType name="ItemData" mixed="true">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Item"
                        type="q3:Item" xmlns:q3="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x60780" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexType name="Item">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="No"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="No_2"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Description"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Search_Description" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Description_2"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Base_Unit_of_Measure" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Price_Unit_Conversion" type="xsd:int" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Unit_Price"
                        type="xsd:decimal" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Duty_Due_Percent"
                        type="xsd:decimal" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Duty_Code"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Gross_Weight"
                        type="xsd:decimal" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Net_Weight"
                        type="xsd:decimal" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Unit_Volume"
                        type="xsd:decimal" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Freight_Type"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Tariff_No"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Duty_Unit_Conversion" type="xsd:decimal" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Country_Region_Purchased_Code" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Blocked"
                        type="xsd:boolean" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Price_Includes_VAT" type="xsd:boolean" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="VAT_Bus_Posting_Gr_Price" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Gen_Prod_Posting_Group" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Country_Region_of_Origin_Code" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Tax_Group_Code"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="VAT_Prod_Posting_Group" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Manufacturer_Code" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Item_Category_Code" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Product_Group_Code" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Expiration_Calculation" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Common_Item_No"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Last_Date_Modified" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Recency_From_Date" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Recency_To_Date"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Status_Code"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Rock_Bottom_Price" type="xsd:boolean" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Buy_Hit"
                        type="xsd:boolean" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Test_Winner"
                        type="xsd:boolean" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Inventory"
                        type="xsd:decimal" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Item_Status_Display_Text" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Not_Homologated"
                        type="xsd:boolean" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Last_Direct_Cost"
                        type="xsd:decimal" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Unit_List_Price"
                        type="xsd:decimal" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ItemVariant"
                        type="q4:ItemVariant" xmlns:q4="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x60780" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ItemVendor"
                        type="q5:ItemVendor" xmlns:q5="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x60780" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ItemSalesPrice"
                        type="q6:ItemSalesPrice" xmlns:q6="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x60780" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ItemTranslation"
                        type="q7:ItemTranslation" xmlns:q7="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x60780" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"
                        name="ItemDistributionChannel" type="q8:ItemDistributionChannel"
                        xmlns:q8="urn:microsoft-dynamics-nav/xmlports/x60780" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexType name="ItemVariant">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Code"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Description"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Description_2"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Variant_Promo"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Variant_Inventory" type="xsd:decimal" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexType name="ItemVendor">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Vendor_No"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Lead_Time_Calculation" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Vendor_Item_No"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Variant_Code"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" default="false"
                        name="Primary_Vendor" type="xsd:boolean" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexType name="ItemSalesPrice">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Sales_Type"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Sales_Code"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Starting_Date"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Currency_Code"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Variant_Code"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Unit_Of_Measure_Code" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Minimum_Quantity"
                        type="xsd:decimal" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Ending_Date"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Unit_Price"
                        type="xsd:decimal" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Price_Includes_VAT" type="xsd:boolean" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="VAT_Bus_Posting_Grp_Price" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Action_Price"
                        type="xsd:boolean" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexType name="ItemTranslation">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Variant_Code"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Language_Code"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Description"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Description_2"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexType name="ItemDistributionChannel">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Item_No"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Variant_Code"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Responsibility_Center" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Start_Date"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Distribution_Channel_Code" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Item_Description"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Item_Description_2" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Language_Code"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Promo_From_Date"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Promo_Until_Date"
                        type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Recency_From_Date_Distr" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
                        name="Recency_To_Date_Distr" type="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message
        name="OutboundItemTransferIISWebService_ItemTransfer_InputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ItemTransfer" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message
        name="OutboundItemTransferIISWebService_ItemTransfer_OutputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ItemTransferResponse" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="OutboundItemTransferIISWebService">
        <wsdl:operation name="ItemTransfer">
            <wsdl:input
                wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/OutboundItemTransferIISWebService/OutboundItemTransferIISWebService/ItemTransfer"
                message="tns:OutboundItemTransferIISWebService_ItemTransfer_InputMessage" />
            <wsdl:output
                wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/OutboundItemTransferIISWebService/OutboundItemTransferIISWebService/ItemTransferResponse"
                message="tns:OutboundItemTransferIISWebService_ItemTransfer_OutputMessage" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="WSHttpBinding_OutboundItemTransferIISWebService"
        type="tns:OutboundItemTransferIISWebService">
        <wsp:PolicyReference
            URI="#WSHttpBinding_OutboundItemTransferIISWebService_policy" />
        <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="ItemTransfer">
            <soap12:operation
                soapAction="http://tempuri.org/OutboundItemTransferIISWebService/OutboundItemTransferIISWebService/ItemTransfer"
                style="document" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="OutboundItemTransferIISWebService">
        <wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_OutboundItemTransferIISWebService"
            binding="tns:WSHttpBinding_OutboundItemTransferIISWebService">
            <soap12:address
                location="http://mdnmt2.ms.local/wc3/entw/OutboundItemTransferIISWebService.svc" />
            <wsa10:EndpointReference>
                <wsa10:Address>http://mdnmt2.ms.local/wc3/entw/OutboundItemTransferIISWebService.svc</wsa10:Address>
            </wsa10:EndpointReference>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Some additions: I tried the [answer] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24676607/6504528) of a similar question with the same result!! I added logging to the class and can see that the correct value for the action is set.

It seems to be that something removes all Headers in the Karaf installation before the request is send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Install *cxf-ws-addr* (`feature:install cxf-ws-addr`) in Karaf.

### This seems to be a missing or buggy dependency in the camel-cxf feature of apache karaf.

**From the beginning**:

Like I mentioned before, I added an Interceptor which should add the action header and this didn't worked. So I debugged the whole Interceptor-Chain of my Request and checked what every Interceptor is doing (yes, every Interceptor). To find the differences I have done this for standalone and with remote debugging for karaf.

I found out, that the Interceptor mentioned before is not doing anything usefull (so don't use it) and inside karaf the Interceptor *[org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.impl.MAPAggregatorImpl](https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/browse/~tag=cxf-3.1.5/cxf/rt/ws/addr/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/ws/addressing/impl/MAPAggregatorImpl.java)* isn't used at all. I have checked the installed bundle's and the dependency tree of maven and indeed, the maven dependency camel-cxf references *cxf-rt-ws-addr* (which contains the Interceptor). But the feature in karaf does not.

This is really nasty, because (in my opinion) one of the benefits of the bundle features is, that they represent the maven dependency hierarchy and I don't have to manage them myself!